# How can I use available native OPENCV library in JAVA?

Tags: java, opencv

I want to use available native OPENCV library in JAVA.I try following code line:

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java2411");
```

but each time, I don't want to use version name in code line. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

`System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`

Then, check the library version with:

`Core.VERSION`